What is the Equivalent Py spark code for the below Databricks SQL
I have below Databricks SQL code (with filter conditions) and wanted to convert to pyspark code but unable get any idea. I searched on google but getting only pyspark filter condition but I don't see any example that fits my use case
select
account_doc_num,

ROUND(coalesce(Sum(tbl.Amnt) FILTER(WHERE tbl.AmntType='type1' AND tbl.line_type='D'),0),2) AS Sls_Inv,
ROUND(coalesce(Sum(tbl.Amnt) FILTER(WHERE tbl.AmntType='type1' AND tbl.line_type='GVAT'),0),2) AS GVAT,

ROUND(coalesce(Sum(tbl.Amnt) FILTER(WHERE tbl.AmntType='type2' AND tbl.line_type='vat'),0),2) AS VAT,
ROUND(coalesce(Sum(tbl.Amnt) FILTER(WHERE tbl.AmntType='type2' AND tbl.line_type='K'),0),2) AS Pur_Inv,

ROUND((Sls_Inv + GVAT + VAT + Pur_Inv),2) AS Diff
    
from
DeltaTable as tbl
group by account_doc_num

Below is the pyspark code I wrote and I want to add the filter conditions for sum function. What I want is the equivalent pyspark function/code for Databricks Filter with where condition.
df_group=(
    df_vat.groupby("account_doc_num")
    .agg(
       sum("Amnt").alias("Sls_Inv"),
       sum("Amnt").alias("GVAT"),
       sum("Amnt").alias("VAT"),
       sum("Amnt").alias("Pur_Inv")
    )
)


the trick for these problems is to think of the solution in vanilla SQL and then convert that to spark-SQL

You can have sum run over a case/when expression e.g.:
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

.agg(
       F.sum(F.when(F.col(AmntType)=='type1' AND F.col("line_type") =='D', F.col("Amnt")).otherwise(0)).alias("Sls_Inv"),

This will count Amnt when the condition is true otherwise the row provides 0.  You can create a decent amount of expression complexity as long as they return 0 and don't have aggregate functions in them (e.g. no nested aggregations).
There are various ways to structure this in your code, google for sumif pyspark and spark combinations.

Thank you so much . I was able to convert the Spark SQL to Py spark with this snippet.
